# css display: inline-block issue

Tags: html, css

i was trying to work on html,css and i got a problem. i am using display: inline-block so that my list items cover all the width of the header. but instead of covering whole width it just floats to the left.
here is a demo of html/css on jsfiddle,
http://jsfiddle.net/oso6x7cd/

html

```
<nav id="globalheader" class="globalheader gh-selected-tab-iphone" role="navigation" aria-label="Global Navigation" data-hires="false" data-analytics-region="global nav" lang="en-US">
            <div id="gh-content" class="gh-content">
                <div class="gh-nav">
                    <div class="gh-nav-view">
                        <ul class="gh-nav-list">
                            <li class="gh-tab gh-tab-apple"><a class="gh-tab-link" href="/"><span class="gh-tab-inner"><span class="gh-text-replace">Apple</span></span></a></li>
                            <li class="gh-tab gh-tab-store"><a class="gh-tab-link" href="http://store.apple.com/us"><span class="gh-tab-inner"><span class="gh-text-replace">Store</span></span></a></li>
                            <li class="gh-tab gh-tab-mac"><a class="gh-tab-link" href="/mac/"><span class="gh-tab-inner"><span class="gh-text-replace">Mac</span></span></a></li>
                            <li class="gh-tab gh-tab-iphone"><a class="gh-tab-link" href="/iphone/"><span class="gh-tab-inner"><span class="gh-text-replace">iPhone</span></span></a></li>
                            <li class="gh-tab gh-tab-watch"><a class="gh-tab-link" href="/watch/"><span class="gh-tab-inner"><span class="gh-text-replace">Watch</span></span></a></li>
                            <li class="gh-tab gh-tab-ipad"><a class="gh-tab-link" href="/ipad/"><span class="gh-tab-inner"><span class="gh-text-replace">iPad</span></span></a></li>
                            <li class="gh-tab gh-tab-ipod"><a class="gh-tab-link" href="/ipod/"><span class="gh-tab-inner"><span class="gh-text-replace">iPod</span></span></a></li>
                            <li class="gh-tab gh-tab-itunes"><a class="gh-tab-link" href="/itunes/"><span class="gh-tab-inner"><span class="gh-text-replace">iTunes</span></span></a></li>
                            <li class="gh-tab gh-tab-support"><a class="gh-tab-link" href="/support/"><span class="gh-tab-inner"><span class="gh-text-replace">Support</span></span></a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div><!--/gh-nav-->
            </div>
        </nav>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting an element to `display:inline-block;` does not make it fill it's container's width.

Setting `display:table; width:100%;` to the `ul` element and `display:table-cell;` to the `li` elements seems to do the trick and is relatively simple.

Updated fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/oso6x7cd/1/

See an updated fiddle with a minimal working example along with media queries to change the padding of the menuitems as the browser window gets smaller:

http://jsfiddle.net/oso6x7cd/2/

Another update to make the nav-bar narrower according to the screen size: http://jsfiddle.net/oso6x7cd/3/

Comment: thanks it worked but not like i wanted. can you take a look at the this header? http://www.apple.com/iphone/ i want to know how it works. the list items cover the whole width and when we resize the browser window, the extra gap between list items finishes step by step.

Comment: The list items on apple.com/iphone do not fill the entire screen.  The site has a max-width of 980px.  Then they use media queries to apply different styles when the browser window is smaller, in this case, just a smaller padding on the list-items and smaller font-size.

Comment: sorry my mistake, i meant the list items cover the whole width of 980px. the trick you showed me was good but the last child has padding to the right which looks bad. how can i remove it make it look the site i provided.

Comment: it is good this time. thank you again. i really appreciate your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

In fact inline-block is working fine. That's the normal behavior for inline-block.